# Change Table column width to avoid truncated output

Tags: powershell

My console output is too small - the IP addresses I'm getting output are truncated.

I know how to format output as a table, however, I am outputting data from a loop, and when i pipeline each output to a `format-table`, I get a nice column width, but 3 blank lines+2 lines for the headline for every one line of actual data. This is quite annoying, and I could not find anything online on how to widen the columns WITHOUT using Format-Table.

**What is a good way of either changing the size in general, OR using `Format-Table` on the entire loop?**

I do **not** want to append every output to a variable or a file, and then print it to the console - it needs to appear loop for loop in the console.

Here's what I mean, in case you wondering:

Before:

```
Name          IPv4Address  
----          -----------  
PC12315274    192.168.10...
PC17245658    192.168.10...
NB12346679    192.168.12.38
PC12245614    192.168.10...
SV12347348    192.168.10...
PC62345678    192.168.10...
SV12165667    192.168.17.28
```

When using `Format-Table` in my loop:

```
Name       IPv4Address  
----       -----------  
PC12315274 192.168.12.129



Name       IPv4Address  
----       -----------  
PC62345678 192.168.14.161



Name       IPv4Address  
----       -----------  
PC12165667 192.168.11.123



Name       IPv4Address  
----       -----------  
NB12555662 192.168.17.125
```

Here is the relevant code:

```
foreach ( $subnet in (7..100)) {
    foreach ( $client in (1..253)) {
        get-adcomputer -filter "IPv4Address -eq '192.168.$subnet.$client'" -Properties * `
            | select Name, IPv4Address
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your actual code?  Without seeing it I can't be sure, but try appending the `-Autosize` parameter to `Format-Table` - it's specifically designed to help with situations like this, as per [the help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-6). Also, I assume by 'loop' you are using `foreach(...) {...}` - if you replace this with `Foreach-Object` on the pipeline, you can then pipe the results to `Format-Table` and avoid your second issue.  But, as I say, without your code, it's hard to say.

Comment: Done, i added the `| Format-Table` after the first pipeline in the inner loop, i tried putting it behind the outer loop but that didnt work

Comment: You could even collect the output of both loops when you place a `$var = ` in Front of the first loop and output everything together. ;-)

Comment: I know,thats why i specifically said that i do NOT want to output everything together, but piece by piece as it goes :P

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  I can see the full name and IP Address without using `Format-Table`.  Anything else you've not included?  incidentally, this looks incredibly inefficient as it will perform about 24000 AD lookups to check each address in the ranges given.  Is there some way you could grab the whole list, then filter on the client?

Comment: Hmmm ... if you don't like the way Powershell does it for you you will have to parse the output by yourself and format it the way you want. What do you want to do with the output? If you want to do further steps in your script I expect it to does not matter how it looks. It's important the the relevant information is avaiable. If you want a nice output you could create a HTML report or use `Out-GridView`.

Comment: I added $ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue" above that because, well, i dont want big red errors for every single IP that has no device... but other than that, its the same. The truncated IPs are very confusing - for example, i just made a run of the script, and everything up to 192.168.10.48 was fine.  THEN i ran the SAME script again, but this time, everything from 192.168.10.10 was truncated.

Comment: @Olaf its just an examplary state, i need to console output not trucated, but in one table - exactly like i described it. this isnt extremely important, but i was really confused about it and would like to know what can be done about this seemingly simple issue

Comment: Seems like a very inefficient and slow way to do this, surely it's easier to get all the subnets & clients in one query eg `$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter 'IPv4Address -like "192.168.*"' -Properties Name,IPv4Address` and then filter on subnet from there `$computers | where IPv4Address -like "192.168.11.*"} | Format-Table -AutoSize` _(note: code is for example and not tested)_

Comment: Filtering by IP-Address doesnt accept wildcards as far as i know (it doesnt like -like, only -eq / -ne), but yea, like i said, this is just a test for later on, and this is not the issue x)

Answer (score 2):

I've found that piping `Select-Object` output to `Format-Table` can cause similar issues. Try piping directly to ft without Selecting first

I also would recommend only querying AD once, then filtering addresses within powershell"

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * -Properties ipv4address | 
where {
    $_.ipv4address -ne $null -and 
    $_.ipv4address.split(".")[2] -in 7..100 -and 
    $_.ipv4address.split(".")[3] -in 1..253} | 
ft name,ipv4address -autosize
```

Comment: Yea, that also works, good to know it might be related to the selecting... And yea, i know querying AD only once would perform better, however i want it to be sorted and in a nice order, and you know how much of a pain sorting IP addresses can be... but thanks nonetheless!

Comment: There's a great trick to sorting IPs: `$ips | Sort-Object -Property { [System.Version]$_ }`